# R software - create a directed and weighted graph from an adjacency matrix

Tags: r, igraph

## Introducing

I am using igraph package on R. What I am trying to do is plotting out  a graph with directed edges with theirs widths displaying weights. Some vertex for particular reasons are more important than others so they are coloured different

Here is the script:

**make originary data frame a numeric matrix**

```
adj_matrix <- as.matrix(matrice_adiacenze95_totale)
```

**create a graph object**

```
grafo95 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adj_matrix, mode = "directed", weighted = TRUE, diag = TRUE, add.colnames = NULL)
```

**add an attribute for recognise certain nodes**

```
V(grafo95)[11]$importance <- 1
V(grafo95)[12]$importance <- 1
V(grafo95)[13]$importance <- 1
V(grafo95)[14]$importance <- 1
V(grafo95)[15]$importance <- 1
V(grafo95)[16]$importance <- 1
V(grafo95)[18]$importance <- 1
V(grafo95)[22]$importance <- 1
V(grafo95)[25]$importance <- 1
V(grafo95)[26]$importance <- 1
V(grafo95)[30]$importance <- 1
V(grafo95)[31]$importance <- 1
V(grafo95)[34]$importance <- 1
V(grafo95)[37]$importance <- 1
V(grafo95)[38]$importance <- 1
```

**improving visualization layout**

```
auto <- layout.davidson.harel(grafo95)
```

**plot the graph**

```
plot(grafo95, layout = auto, vertex.size = 10, vertex.color=c( "pink", "skyblue")[0+(V(grafo95)$importance==1)], edge.arrow.size = .1)
```

**What I get graphically**
[Firstly I whish that edges represent their weights, secondly that nodes had the color I chose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCVIT.png)

Comment: You assigned weights to the _nodes_ not the edges. What should the weight of an edge be?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However I am a little sorry, probably it dues to my lack of knowledge of this topic, or my weak english but I can't understand what you are asking me. If I type "E(grafo95)$weight" on the console I get weights. Who do they belong to?

Comment: You question did not mention  "E(grafo95)$weight".  Those do belong to the edges.

Comment: Ok, you're right